# Create a Vigenere style encryption with a custom substitution in python

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

I want to create a Vigenere style encryption in python, but with two keys. The first key should determinate the substitution by changing the alphabets in the second key to encrypt words and sentences with this new substitution. The first key should consist of numbers and the second one of letters. Is such a project even possible in Python without having to hardcode everyone of the 26 possible alphabets in lists and then changing them?

Ps: I know the result will not be safe, I want to do this as a practice in programming.

Comment: I think you may be reaching for `list(string.ascii_lowercase)`.

Comment: Of course you don't need to hardcode the shifted alphabets. Actually you don't even need to build them: since they only are a helper to avoid calculations for a human encryptor, while computers usually do calculations :) But you're expected to try yourself, and then post what you tried, and where you're stuck. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)